# Navbar toggles but doesn't work when testing locally on mobile device

Tags: testing, mobile, hyperlink, twitter-bootstrap-3, href

I have followed numberous tutorials to create a responsive website with Bootstrap 3. However, when I test my site locally on my mobile device the Href links don't appear to work. The navbar toggles but will not expand when touched neither does the nav links as well as modal links. The only link that does work is a link to facebook. My question is does the site need to be live on a server for it to work or have I done something wrong here?

Lets start with my toggling navbar. Works on a desktop but when testing locally on a mobile device touch screen it toggles but doesn't expand when touching the toggle icon. I've tested this on my mobile by copying it across but the toggle element doesn't expand the menu. any help would be appreciated.

```
<div class="jumbotron" id="jumbotron-nav">
    <div class="container">
        <nav class = "navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <div class="container-fluid">

                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type= "button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarpage">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>  
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Archways</a>

                </div>

                <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarpage">

                    <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                        <li><a href = "#Aboutus" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarpage">About us</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "#Roomhire" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarpage">Room Hire</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "#Treatment" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarpage">Treatment</a></li>  
                        <li><a href = "#Meettheteam" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarpage">Meet the team</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#contactus">Contact us</a></li>
                        <li><a href = "#Findus" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarpage">Find us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share your code to demonstrate the problem.  See   http://sscce.org/

Comment: How do I add my code? it is too long to add here. I have added the site to drop box downloaded it to my phone and tablet and extracted it and loaded it. The menu toggles but doesn't expand when i touch my screen and the href links don't work either the only thing that does work is the link to facebook. PS: sorry I had not replied I didn't realise i had gotten one

Comment: That's why I linked you to http://sscce.org; you should condense your code to something concise which reproduces the problem.

Comment: Okay, but the thing is the href links work when accessing it on desktop. When I do test locally on a mobile as desribed above the href links don't work. So as you can probably understand I don't exactly know where the problem is.

Comment: It feels like you're not reading the linked page.  Does this code snippet exhibit the same problem? `<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation"><div class="navbar-collapse collapse"><ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"><li><a href="#Roomhire" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">Room Hire</a></li></ul></div></nav>` If yes, that is an example of a SSCCE, which helps narrow down the problem.  You said that you can't paste the full code here, so reduce your code to a manageable size which still exhibits the problem.

Comment: Hi. thanks for your help so far. I stripped back the code and that didn't resolve it. The fact is the toggle icon appears as expected (the 3 spans) but when I touch the icon on my mobile device it does nothing. It changes colour and recognises that you put your finger on the screen and touched the icon but the 6 menu items that it has hidden will not appear.

Comment: i'm just wondering, do I need to upload the files and test when hosted on a server? At the moment I am download the website to my phone and accessing the index.html file through the phone?

Comment: I don't know enough about Bootstrap to be able to give you a definitive answer.  I think the answer is "probably not".  I would suggest that you post your stripped-back code that exhibits the same issue (as per http://sscce.org) as an edit to your question so that those who might be able to help you have an easier time doing so.